# How to display a column's Unicode fonts in SSMS Grid Results?

Tags: unicode, fonts, ssms, collation

SSMS [v19.0.1] fonts have been set to **Consolas** for both Text Editor and Grid Results. Unicode fonts are being displayed properly in the SSMS text editor but not in grid results, where they are being rendered as `?`.   The current `database collation` is  `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

I thought the column's fonts might be rendered properly in SSMS grid results if a `column-level collation` was set, so I tried the following

```
 alter table T alter column col nvarchar(512) COLLATE <collation>
```

For `<collation>` I've tried these three:

```
 SQL_AltDiction_CP850_CS_AS 
 SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN2
 Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_SC
```

The last supports `supplemental characters`. But the fonts are still being rendered as question marks in Grid Results. So either the column-level collation approach is not valid or I'm not choosing the proper collation.

The column is storing runic inscriptions and doesn't really need to be sorted. The results just have to be legible.  How to get the Unicode fonts to render in SSMS grid results?

Comment: Can you provide some examples here? I've never had problems with characters rendering in SSMS. In truth, this sounds more like you are using a `varchar` somewhere along the way, as I would expect a � character to display if the character was unknown.

Comment: @Larnu:  I think I may have stumbled on a possible clue.   What datatype is returned by the `replace()` function in  `set nvarcharColumn = replace(varcharColumn, searchChar, N'ᛞ')` ?  I should probably have cast the varcharColumn to nvarchar . Docs say "Returns nvarchar if one of the input arguments is of the nvarchar data type; otherwise, REPLACE returns varchar." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: If even one of the values is an `nvarchar` a `nvarchar` is returned, @Tim . I've also tried replicating your problem, and I can't. In a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6vEf13DK) I get the character, in [ADS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajVlj.png) I get character, *and* in [SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H1kV.png) I get the character. I would suggest taking the time to provide the code yo are using, and a [mre].

Comment: @Larnu: Thank you very much for taking the time to check!  It was more than a week ago that I converted the character entities (e.g. `&daeg;` ) to the Unicode character, and I didn't save my query, but I may have neglected to put the `N` in front of the quoted Unicode character.  When it is not supplied, I get the question mark, so that's most likely what happened:  `select replace('&daeg;','&daeg;','ᛞ')` .

Comment: Yes, `'ᛞ'` *would* result in `'?'` as the character will be outside of the codepage. The only way it would be retained would be if you were using a UTF-8 collation, as then `varchar` values are stored as UTF-8 (`nvarchar` is stored as a UCS-2/UTF-16 even in UTF-8 collations mind)

Answer (score 0):

The behavior where the font is being rendered as a question mark was surely the result of an error in my T-SQL code, a missing `N` in front of the quoted Unicode character error in my query when I converted the character entity (e.g. `&daeg;`) to the Unicode character (e.g. ᛞ).    Since there's educational value in mistakes, I'm answering the question.

```
     -- this will not preserve the Unicode character unless collation is UTF-8
      select replace('&daeg;','&daeg;','ᛞ') 

     -- should be  
     select replace('&daeg;','&daeg;',N'ᛞ')
```

As @Larnu remarks in a comment above

> ... 'ᛞ' would result in '?' as the character will be outside of the
> codepage. The only way it would be retained would be if you were using
> a UTF-8 collation, as then varchar values are stored as UTF-8
> (nvarchar is stored as a UCS-2/UTF-16 even in UTF-8 collations mind)